# Lepton and strangeness conservation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model

Do I have a misunderstanding here at all? The question states:

> One of the following equations represents a possible decay of the K$^+$ kaon. \begin{align}\mathrm K^+&\to\pi^++\pi^0\\\mathrm K^+&\to\mu^+ +\overline{\nu_\mu}\end{align}
>   State, with a reason, which one of these decays is not possible.

I then see that on the first one that the strangeness isn't conserved, on the right, the strangeness is $+1$ and on the left the strangeness is $0$, then on the second one the lepton number on the left is $0$ then on the right it is $0$ too, the answer however states that the second one is incorrect as the lepton number isn't conserved, despite me working out that it is.

I could be very wrong here, any ideas?

Comment: The $\mu^+$ and $\bar{\nu}_\mu$ are both antileptons so their total lepton number is -2. Strangeness is not a conserved quantity in decays via the weak interaction.

Comment: What about the first one, surely the strangeness works as its under the strong force giving $1$ before and $0$ after? Or does this one interaction ignore the rules?

Comment: The $\bar{s}$ decays to $\bar{u}$ and a $W^+$ in a weak process. This does not conserve strangeness. The $W^+$ decays to $\bar{d}$ and $u$. The original $u$ and the new $\bar{d}$ form a $\pi^+$ and the $u$ and $\bar{u}$ form a $\pi^0$.

Comment: Uuuuh... the first one doesn't conserve electric charge...

Comment: @Eoin: that was an error introduced when the question was edited. The original version did have the first decay as $K^+ \rightarrow \pi^+ + \pi^0$.

Comment: Re the reopen votes, you might want to check [this post in the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71?m=28988673#28988673).  I don't feel strongly about whether it should be closed or not, and in any case the OP has their answer.

Comment: @JohnRennie Dosn't a muon + particle have a lepton number of 1?